# tsvector in sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, tsvector

I've been looking for a way to use tsvector in sqlalchemy (simply like other ones such as INTEGER, etc), but so far it's not clear to me how to do this. I've read that tsvector can be implemented as a type using [UserDefinedType](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.UserDefinedType). After some attempts I'm getting nowhere, someone has a simple way to do this? thanks

Comment: For anyone looking for a basic example see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999486/11750716

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want SQLAlchemy to be able to create schemas with the tsvector type and just retrieve the serialized value in queries, this is what you need:

```
from sqlalchemy import types
class tsvector(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.UnicodeText

@compiles(tsvector, 'postgresql')
def compile_tsvector(element, compiler, **kw):
    return 'tsvector'
```

`tsvector` works like a regular type and you can use it within a table definition. (I forgot where I found the snippet, probably on the SQLAlchemy mailing list or wiki.)

If you need to actually parse tsvector data, it's a little more complicated. The latest version's hstore support might be a good example to follow. However you may find the following snippet useful too. It's old code that's been known to work and is written with pyparsing:

```
from pyparsing import ParserElement, QuotedString, Regex, Group, Suppress, Group, delimitedList, ZeroOrMore, StringEnd
ParserElement.enablePackrat()
lexeme = QuotedString("'")
occurrence_marker = Regex('[1-9][0-9]*[A-D]?')
atom = Group(lexeme('lexeme') + Suppress(':') + Group(delimitedList(occurrence_marker))('markers'))('atom')
tsvector = ZeroOrMore(atom) + StringEnd()
parse_tsvector = tsvector.parseString
```

**Update:**

To query the tsvector column, use the `.op()` method like this:

```
session.query(Model).filter(Model.tsvector.op('@@')(func.plainto_tsquery('search string')))
```

Comment: thanks a lot jd, it works perfectly, in fact I'm so far only interested in retrieving serialized queries, btw, how could I query in sqlalchemy the tsvector column (ts)? this works in postgresql: `select * from boreholes_point_wgs84 where ts @@ to_tsquery('something');`

Comment: You're welcome. I've added how to generate a where clause with the column. Consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it's helpful:)

Comment: thanks again jd, your answer is the winner, you're the best ;)

Comment: I've managed to get something like this working and blogged about it here. I'm [linking to it](http://nibrahim.net.in/2013/11/29/sqlalchemy_and_full_text_searching_in_postgresql.html) in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: You're welcome @Gery. It's been accepted in SQLAlchemy core though so it's mostly useful only as an educational tool.

Comment: For the record, support for TSVECTOR is present in SQLAlchemy since 0.9.0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Postgres, the right way to do it is to use the `TSVECTOR` type definition from `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql` as this will tell `SQLAlchemy` that this is a generated field, if you are using `GENERATED ALWAYS` in Postgres.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import TSVECTOR
from sqlalchemy import Column

ts_col = Column(TSVECTOR)
```

The accepted solution at the top does the trick in some cases but if you are getting

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) cannot insert into column "ts"
DETAIL: Column "ts" is a generated column.
```

you need to make sure you use `sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.TSVECTOR`.