# Create a Full Text Search index with SQLAlchemy on PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I need to create a PostgreSQL Full Text Search index in Python with SQLAlchemy. Here's what I want in SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE person ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT );
CREATE INDEX person_idx ON person USING GIN (to_tsvector('simple', name));
```

Now how do I do the second part with SQLAlchemy when using the ORM:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could create index using `Index` in `__table_args__`. Also I use a function to create `ts_vector` to make it more tidy and reusable if more than one field is required. Something like below:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

def create_tsvector(*args):
    exp = args[0]
    for e in args[1:]:
        exp += ' ' + e
    return func.to_tsvector('english', exp)

class Person(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String)

    __ts_vector__ = create_tsvector(
        cast(func.coalesce(name, ''), postgresql.TEXT)
    )

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            'idx_person_fts',
            __ts_vector__,
            postgresql_using='gin'
        )
    )
```

---

**Update:**
A sample query using index (corrected based on comments):

```
people = Person.query.filter(Person.__ts_vector__.match(expressions, postgresql_regconfig='english')).all()
```

Comment: Could you give an example on how to query the vector? Thanks.

Comment: @sharez with latest version, `query.all()` throws error: `Neither 'BinaryExpression' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'all'`. could you provide alternative to it ?

Comment: @apaleja `match` is an operator, hence it should be within a `filter` method, as such: ```Person.query.filter(Person.__ts_vector__.match(expressions, postgresql_regconfig='english')).all()```

Answer (score 21):

The answer from [@sharez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967498/sharez) is really useful (especially if you need to concatenate columns in your index). For anyone looking to create a tsvector GIN index on a single column, you can simplify the original answer approach with something like:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


Base = declarative_base()

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    textsearch = Column(String)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            'ix_examples_tsv',
            func.to_tsvector('english', textsearch),
            postgresql_using='gin'
            ),
        )
```

Note that the comma following `Index(...)` in `__table_args__` is not a style choice, the value of `__table_args__` must be a tuple, dictionary, or `None`.

If you do need to create a tsvector GIN index on multiple columns, here is another way to get there using [`text()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.text).

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Index, Integer, String, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


Base = declarative_base()

def to_tsvector_ix(*columns):
    s = " || ' ' || ".join(columns)
    return func.to_tsvector('english', text(s))

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'examples'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    atext = Column(String)
    btext = Column(String)

    __table_args__ = (
        Index(
            'ix_examples_tsv',
            to_tsvector_ix('atext', 'btext'),
            postgresql_using='gin'
            ),
        )
```

Comment: Could you give an example on how to query the vector? Thanks.

Comment: @apaleja - see example query at the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837111/tsvector-in-sqlalchemy#13878979

Comment: Note that with this I got: `sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: No literal value renderer is available for literal value "'english'" with datatype REGCONFIG`. I needed to change "english" to `sqlalchemy.literal("english")`.

Comment: Thanks @DustinOprea for your comment! It helped me to fix the same error when upgrading from SQLAlchemy 1.4.x to 2.0.x!

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for this question and answers.

I'd like to add a bit more in case ppl using alembic to manage versions by
using [autogenerate](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html)
which creating the index seems not be detected.

We might end up writing our own alter script which look like.

```py
"""add fts idx

Revision ID: e3ce1ce23d7a
Revises: 079c4455d54d
Create Date: 

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = 'e3ce1ce23d7a'
down_revision = '079c4455d54d'

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    op.create_index('idx_content_fts', 'table_name',
            [sa.text("to_tsvector('english', content)")],
            postgresql_using='gin')


def downgrade():
    op.drop_index('idx_content_fts')
```

Answer (score 10):

It has been answered already by @sharez and @benvc. I needed to make it work with weights though. This is how I did it based on their answers :

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, func, Index, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.operators import op

CONFIG = 'english'

Base = declarative_base()

def create_tsvector(*args):
    field, weight = args[0]
    exp = func.setweight(func.to_tsvector(CONFIG, field), weight)
    for field, weight in args[1:]:
        exp = op(exp, '||', func.setweight(func.to_tsvector(CONFIG, field), weight))
    return exp

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'example'

    foo = Column(String)
    bar = Column(String)

    __ts_vector__ = create_tsvector(
        (foo, 'A'),
        (bar, 'B')
    )

    __table_args__ = (
        Index('my_index', __ts_vector__, postgresql_using='gin'),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for using `op` :D

Comment: Can you give an example of how this would be queried? I am using `query.filter(Example.__ts_vector__.op("@@")(func.websearch_to_tsquery(FTS_CONFIG, search_term)).all()`. However, I always get an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers here were helpful for pointing in the right direction.
Below, a distilled & simplified approach using ORM approach & `TSVectorType` helper from `sqlalchemy-utils` (that is quite basic and can be simply copy/pasted to avoid external dependencies if needed https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/ts_vector.html):

##### Defining a `TSVECTOR` column (`TSVectorType`) in your ORM model (declarative) populated automatically from the source text field(s)

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy_utils.types.ts_vector import TSVectorType
# ^-- https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sqlalchemy_utils/types/ts_vector.html


class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mymodel'
    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    content = sa.Column(sa.String, nullable=False)

    content_tsv = sa.Column(
        TSVectorType("content", regconfig="english"),
        sa.Computed("to_tsvector('english', \"content\")", persisted=True))
    #      ^-- equivalent for SQL:
    #   COLUMN content_tsv TSVECTOR GENERATED ALWAYS AS (to_tsvector('english', "content")) STORED;

    __table_args__ = (
        # Indexing the TSVector column
        sa.Index("idx_mymodel_content_tsv", content_tsv, postgresql_using="gin"), 
    )
```

For additional details on **querying** using ORM, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999486/11750716 (there is an important difference between `SQLAlchemy 1.4` and `SQLAlchemy 2.0`).