# Fuzzy string matching in filter and sorting

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three classes *Author*, *Topic* and *Article* which all contains a column *name*. **I'm trying to implement a typical search functionality where I take a search string *S* and expect to see all entries of the above classes with a *name* somewhat matching that string.** Optimally, I would also like to be able to sort the results according to how well they match *S*.

My best attempt so far is to use a query like:

```
a = session.query(Author).filter(Author.name.ilike(S)).all()
b = session.query(Topic).filter(Topic.name.ilike(S)).all()
c = session.query(Article).filter(Article.name.ilike(S)).all()
```

which I then concatenate into a single list. This works well when the search string *S* is a substring of the names, **but the problem arises when there are spelling mistakes. If I have the names "Test ABC", "Test DEF", "Test GHI", "Test JKL" and search with the string "Tset"** I get 0 results. E.g in Postgres I can use Levenshtein distance and other measurements to handle this, where also sorting according to the likeness becomes trivial. Is there anything similar to this built into SQLAlchemy?

Comment: This is vendor specific - for example if the underlying db is postgres this can be done. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42390204/4711754 for example