# Returning ranked search results using gin index with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, full-text-search, rdbms

I have a GIN index set up for full text search. I would like to get a list of records that match a search query, ordered by rank (how well the record matched the search query). For the result, I only need the record and its columns, I do not need the actual rank value that was used for ordering.

I have the following query, which runs fine and returns the expected results from my postgresql db.

```
SELECT *, ts_rank('{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}', users.textsearchable_index_col, to_tsquery('smit:* | ji:*')) AS rank
FROM users
WHERE users.authentication_method != 2 AND users.textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery('smith:* | ji:*') ORDER 
BY rank desc;
```

I would like to perform this query using sqlalchemy(SA). I understand that 'ts_rank' does not come ready to use in SA. I have tried a number of things, such as

```
proxy = self.db_session.query(User, text(
                """ts_rank('{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}', users.textsearchable_index_col, to_tsquery(:search_str1)) as rank""")). \
                filter(User.authentication_method != 2,
                       text("""users.textsearchable_index_col @@ to_tsquery(:search_str2)""")). \
                params(search_str1=search, search_str2=search). \
                order_by("rank")
```

and also read about using [column property](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#using-column-property/), although I'm not sure if/how I would use that in the solution.

would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Modern example compatible with `SQLAlchemy 1.4` and `SQLAlchemy 2.0` at bottom of following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999486/11750716

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use SQL functions in your queries by using SQLAlchemy [func](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=func#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.func)

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

(db.session.query(User, func.ts_rank('{0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1}', User.textsearchable_index_col, func.to_tsquery('smit:* | ji:*')).label('rank'))
    .filter(User.authentication_method != 2)
    .filter(User.textsearchable_index_col.op('@@')(func.to_tsquery('smit:* | ji:*')))
    .order_by('rank desc')
).all()
```